# I want row where max id

Tags: php, max

My query

```
select max(forum_id) as f_id from forum where topic_id='$fo_id';
```

We want all row record where forum_id is maximum. My query is as above. We success to get Maximum `Forum_id` but We want entire row where max forum_id. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below given query.

```
 SELECT * from tabName where `tabId` IN (select MAX(tabId) from tabName);
```

Comment: if you want count alias then you cans also write query as 
select *, `tabId` as cnts  from tabName  where `tabId` IN (select MAX(tabId) from tabName)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM forum WHERE topic_id='$fo_id' ORDER BY forum_id DESC LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
select * from forum where topic_id='$fo_id' order by forum_id desc
```

I think it will work.